# How to have Appendix A, Appendix B, Appendix C... in Classicthesis LyX version

Tags: lyx, appendices, classicthesis

The Classicthesis LyX template presets the Appendix as a chapter (or a child document), with chapter number "A". So the first section appears as A.1, and the first subsection appears as  A.1.1 and so on in the Classicthesis file (or the parent document). That is, all subsequent sections and subsections are numbered starting with "A".

I want to customize the Appendix Chapter in Classicthesis LyX version 4.2 to have

A Appendix for Chapter 1

A.1

A.1.1

A.1.1.1

B Appendix for Chapter 2

B.1

B.1.1

B.1.1.1

C Appendix for Chapter 3

C.1

C.1.1

C.1.1.1

This style is commonly used in PhD thesis, which is perfect for many equations, figures and tables in Appendix. For example, the fifth equation in Section C is labeled as (C.5).

Comment: `classicthesis` has many problems. But your question is unclear. You want to have the `section` numbers also being letters? The appendix chapters numbers are formatted with letters already.

Comment: Essentially I do not want chapter number. I just want section number to be capital letter. The template setting is that Appendix is a chapter, with chapter number: A. So the first section is A.1 in the parent LyX file. The first subsection is A.1.1.   Therefore, all subsequent sections and subsections are numbered starting with A. I just want to follow the standard PhD thesis Appendix style by linking  A to Chapter 1, B to Chapter 2 and C to Chapter 3

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out by myself! Use the Appendix template as the first Appendix section for Chapter 1. Use it again to generate a new child document for Chapter 2, of course, have to give a new name. In the compiled parent document (that is, classicthesis.lyx), the second child document automatically becomes Appendix B! Now I start loving this template more!

Since this is not explained by the template, I wish this does not imply that my question was too stupid: )

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of what you mean by "Use the Appendix template as the first Appendix section..."? There are many codes and I am not sure what you refer to (not sure either about what you call a child document... is it an `\include{}`?)